# What do the numbers in parentheses near the commands mean?

Tags: manpage

In some manuals online I see numbers in parentheses following the commands, like  (sshd(8), ssh_config(5), etc.). What does this mean, and why is it important to indicate/show the number?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the manual page for the `man` command. Ie. `man man`

> The table below shows the section numbers of the manual followed by the types of pages they contain.

```
1   Executable programs or shell commands
2   System calls (functions provided by the kernel)
3   Library calls (functions within program libraries)
4   Special files (usually found in /dev)
5   File formats and conventions eg /etc/passwd
6   Games
7   Miscellaneous (including macro  packages  and  convenâ
    tions), e.g. man(7), groff(7)
8   System administration commands (usually only for root)
9   Kernel routines [Non standard]
```

By the way it is also a dropdownbox on the openssh website:

[image]